# Unable to access external database from Heroku App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have rails 3.2.13 application running on heroku. I want my application to access a remote MySQL database. For that I have changed the DATABASE_URL in heroku config. Here is how I did it

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql2://user_name:password@171.121.123.120:3306/database_name
```

Above command changes the database_url successfully.

But when I try to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` it errors out. Below is the error I get

```
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'user_name'@'ec2-23-20-128-131.compute-1.amazonaws.com'    (using password: YES)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
```

I have added wild card like %.%.%.% at my MySQL server to allow any IP to access database but even that is not working. I have able to access database from my local dev machine after adding those wild cards.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your credentials defined in /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb ?  It looks like the migrate command is trying to pull the info from that file.

EDIT: sorry, the code block you had got cutoff on my screen.  Does everything look right in the client.rb file?